# How to create a while loop with tolerance

Tags: python

I'm trying to do some control engineering where I start with a certain value, for example, `x = 5` and in the end, it should return `x`. The goal, in the end, is to find a value for `x`, where `x (beginning) == x (end)`.

I was thinking about creating a while loop and just adding or subtracting a certain stepsize on `x(beginning)` till it reaches equilibrium. However, I want some tolerance in my while loop. Like `x(beginning) ==x(end)+0.1` would also be fine.

I don't know how to create this in Python and I'm not sure whether this is even the right way to accomplish this

Comment: please add some more information

Comment: `x_beg < x_end + epsilon and x_beg > x_end - epsilon` ? It's really unclear what you want to do with x inside your loop.

Comment: That works fine, thanks! I dont know why i didnt come up with this myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `math.isclose()`. With that you can specify both a relative and an absolute tolerance limit.

```
isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-9, abs_tol=0.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
# in this example, x is the beginning value, y is the end value
x = 5
y = 10
tolerance = 0.1
while True:
    if abs(y-x) <= tolerance:
        break
    # put your code here
    x += 1 # or something else
```

Comment: And what happens if `x == y +0.01` ? User want to check if `x` is close enough to `y`, not if `x` is equals to `y` plus an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Thanks, this one is genius